# Javascript snippet freezes Firefox3.6

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox3.6

This code is freezing Firefox 3.6.

```
 // Google Code for Converted Users Remarketing List
    function converted_remarketing() {
        window.google_conversion_id = 1018522404;
        window.google_conversion_language = 'en';
        window.google_conversion_format = '3';
        window.google_conversion_color = '666666';
        window.google_conversion_label = 'e9x2CKzhXXXXpNbV5QM';
        window.google_conversion_value = 0;
        var a = document.createElement('script');
        a.type = 'text/javascript';
        a.async = true;
        a.src = 'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js';
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
    }

converted_remarketing();
```

Example page: http://jsfiddle.net/LLSu4/11/show/

Looks like it has something to do with the script insertion. The funny thing is that I copied the insertion snippet from Google Analytics code that works flawlessly.

So the question is, why is it freezing Firefox 3.6 and why it doesn't freeze Firefox3.6 when a very similar code is ran to load Google Analytics script ga.js?

Comment: What parameter are you supposed to be passing into the method?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts It doesn;t matter. I removed it to make it easier. Still freezes.

Comment: Why would anyone still use FF3.x nowadays?!

Comment: @ThiefMaster: For example, some people use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS or other [distributions with non-rolling releases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release#Counter-examples:_non-rolling_releases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently related to a `document.write()` in conversion.js.

See http://jsfiddle.net/LLSu4/19/

ga.js does not use `document.write`, hence no problem there.

Using `document.write` in an inserted script is never a good idea. This will confuse the HTML engine. You'll find that bugzilla has several bugs concerning `appendChild` and `document.write`, e.g. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607222

Comment: So a possible solution would be to overwrite document.write with something else, like you did in that fiddle?

Comment: Yes. That img is typical tracking pixel, so you might as well insert it using DOM methods without losing functionality. However, a general solution is pretty tricky. You'd either have to parse markup in JS or use the browser's parser via documentFragment or a hidden iFrame or such. The latter is not guaranteed to work: A colleague of mine had issues with IE and Flash content.